# twisted poincare duality

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a closed smooth oriented manifold of dimension $n$. Suppose that $\pi:L\longrightarrow M$ is a line bundle with a flat connection $\nabla$. Consider the space of $L$-valued differential forms: $$\Omega^{*}(L):=\Omega^{*}(M)\otimes L$$
The flat connection induce a differential operator on $\Omega^{*}(L)$, therefore we can define the $L$-valued de Rham cohomology (or twisted cohomology) $H^{*}(M;L)$. So is there a Poincar$\acute{e}$ duality for such twisted cohomology by a flat line bundle?

Comment: Try chapter 2 of the book by Bott-Tu.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a perfect pairing
$$
H^p(M;L)\otimes H^q(M;L^*)\to\mathbb{R},
$$
$p+q=n$.

Comment: In fact, even if $M$ is not oriented you get something similar only instead of $L^*$ you get $L$ (dualized and) twisted by the orientation sheaf.